# Dynamically display value in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

In my template, I need to display the text 'Passed' only if `item.name === 'michael'`is not true.My component has data `courses[]` coming from its parent. I have two interfaces Courses and Teachers where each course id has its own Teacher data.

Here is my code:

```
  @Input() courses[];
  isRequired = false;
  ngonInit() {
     for (const entry of courses ) {
      this.onCheckData(entry);
    }
  }

  onCheckData(singleList: Courses) {
    this.someService.someObservable(singleList.id).subscribe( item => {
        if (item.name === 'michael') {
            this.isRequired = true; 
         }
        });
       }

  declare interface courses {
      id: number;
      name: string;
      price: number;
}

declare interface Teachers {
  name : string;
  address: string;
}
```

Setting true/false with variable `isRequired` does not seem to work. someObservable() is returning an `Observable<Teacher>` using http.

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let listing of courses">
      <td>
        {{listing.name}}
      </td>
      <td>
        <span *ngIf="!isRequired"> Passed </span> // not working here
      </td>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

isRequired will be set for all components, if one of the items has the name.

You could try `listing.name === 'michael'`, if the name is inside of the listing.

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let listing of courses">
      <td>
        {{listing.name}}
      </td>
      <td>
        <span *ngIf="listing.name === 'michael'"> Passed </span> // not working here
      </td>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `isRequired` should also be an observable.

Try like this:

```
public isRequired$ = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);
```

and then

```
onCheckData(singleList: Courses) {
this.someService.someObservable(singleList.id).subscribe( item => {
    if (item.name === 'michael') {
        this.isRequired$.next(true);
     }
    });
   }
```

Not the dollar convention for an observable

```
<span *ngIf="!isRequired$"> Passed </span>
```